# command button will not open report on laptop but works on other computers

Tags: ms-access

Ok, I am starting to get frustrated. We made this access program to put part constraints in and everything seems to work on the PC's we have tried it on. My boss was showing someone the program on his PC but when he got to the buttons that open the reports they would not open. Does anyone know what could be causing this.

Comment: I forgot to mention that he is using a laptop with a dual monitor. Not sure if that helps.

Comment: I think that we might need more information than that. For example, how  did you impliment the buttons? Do you have some code snippits. Also check the settings in Access, sometimes code execution is blocked for security.

Comment: I used the macro builder for the button since the report doesn't require anything special to open. I think that when I used the Access interface I had to open the report in design view first then open in in print preview for it to open correctly. There were no error messages and the reports have opened fine on other PC's. As far as security goes we clicked enable macros. I don't understand why the forms would open but not the reports.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I really hate to answer my own question but I found the problem and the report is opening as of right now. I only came across this by chance but it seemed to work. I changed the setting of Display on SharePoint Site to Do Not Display. I never noticed that option before so I gave it a try. SharePoint is on the laptop which I didn't know at the time and I know nothing about it, but at least it shows on the screen now.